# Android app signed ANR when disconnecting from BT

Tags: java, android-studio, android-6.0-marshmallow, intentservice, android-anr-dialog

I'm having a hard time searching for the possible cause of an ANR in Android 6.+ devices, my app uses an IntentService to connect to a device via BT, when the connection is lost the app freezes, I call:

```
getActivity().unbindService(btConnectionService);
```

when the app exits the Activity that requires the connection to happen, and there the app freezes too, **it only happens when the app is signed and is running on Android 6 or higher**, on Lower Android versions works without problems, I have gotten the ANR log from the play store from a Moto X pure running Android 6, here it is:

```
suspend all histogram: Sum: 2.304ms 99% C.I. 0.148us-388us Avg: 44.307us Max: 388us DALVIK THREADS (28): "Signal Catcher" daemon prio=5 tid=2 Runnable | group="system" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x32c0c0a0 self=0x7fab7dd000 | sysTid=24118 nice=0 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0x7fb0e7f440 | state=R schedstat=( 236109479 2523697 103 ) utm=10 stm=13 core=4 HZ=100 | stack=0x7fb0d83000-0x7fb0d85000 stackSize=1013KB | held mutexes= "mutator lock"(shared held) native: #00 pc 000000000048c300 /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art15DumpNativeStackERNSt3__113basic_ostreamIcNS0_11char_traitsIcEEEEiPKcPNS_9ArtMethodEPv+236) native: #01 pc 000000000045b9fc /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZNK3art6Thread4DumpERNSt3__113basic_ostreamIcNS1_11char_traitsIcEEEE+220) native: #02 pc 0000000000468178 /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art14DumpCheckpoint3RunEPNS_6ThreadE+688) native: #03 pc 0000000000469090 /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art10ThreadList13RunCheckpointEPNS_7ClosureE+276) native: #04 pc 000000000046974c /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art10ThreadList4DumpERNSt3__113basic_ostreamIcNS1_11char_traitsIcEEEE+188) native: #05 pc 000000000046a034 /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art10ThreadList14DumpForSigQuitERNSt3__113basic_ostreamIcNS1_11char_traitsIcEEEE+492) native: #06 pc 000000000043393c /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art7Runtime14DumpForSigQuitERNSt3__113basic_ostreamIcNS1_11char_traitsIcEEEE+96) native: #07 pc 0000000000440f14 /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art13SignalCatcher13HandleSigQuitEv+1256) native: #08 pc 0000000000441b84 /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art13SignalCatcher3RunEPv+548) native: #09 pc 0000000000066274 /system/lib64/libc.so (_ZL15__pthread_startPv+52) native: #10 pc 000000000001ef44 /system/lib64/libc.so (__start_thread+16) (no managed stack frames)

"main" prio=5 tid=1 Suspended | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x753bf828 self=0x7fb1bbba00 | sysTid=24116 nice=0 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0x7fb519afe8 | state=S schedstat=( 184829068823 8596353264 31818 ) utm=18262 stm=220 core=1 HZ=100 | stack=0x7fd9722000-0x7fd9724000 stackSize=8MB | held mutexes= at com.lamotte.waterlinkspin.WLSCommThread.cancel(WLSCommThread.java:174) at com.lamotte.waterlinkspin.WLSComm.killThreads(WLSComm.java:358) - locked <0x0492c12c> (a com.lamotte.waterlinkspin.WLSComm) at com.lamotte.waterlinkspin.WLSComm.stop(WLSComm.java:365) - locked <0x0492c12c> (a com.lamotte.waterlinkspin.WLSComm) at com.lamotte.waterlinkspin.WLSComm.connectionLost(WLSComm.java:371) at com.lamotte.waterlinkspin.WLSDevice$2.handleMessage(WLSDevice.java:238) at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5443) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke!(Native method) at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728) at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)

"ReferenceQueueDaemon" daemon prio=5 tid=3 Waiting | group="system" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x32c0c100 self=0x7fb1bbf600 | sysTid=24119 nice=0 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0x7fb0d80440 | state=S schedstat=( 23969536 12093020 148 ) utm=1 stm=1 core=0 HZ=100 | stack=0x7fb0c7e000-0x7fb0c80000 stackSize=1037KB | held mutexes= at java.lang.Object.wait!(Native method) - waiting on <0x0d5fd7f5> (a java.lang.Class) at java.lang.Daemons$ReferenceQueueDaemon.run(Daemons.java:147) - locked <0x0d5fd7f5> (a java.lang.Class) at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)

"FinalizerDaemon" daemon prio=5 tid=4 Waiting | group="system" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x32c0c160 self=0x7fa451c000 | sysTid=24120 nice=0 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0x7fb0c7b440 | state=S schedstat=( 135881454 19320204 203 ) utm=13 stm=0 core=3 HZ=100 | stack=0x7fb0b79000-0x7fb0b7b000 stackSize=1037KB | held mutexes= at java.lang.Object.wait!(Native method) - waiting on <0x0219c98a> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue) at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:423) at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:101) - locked <0x0219c98a> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue) at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:72) at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.run(Daemons.java:185) at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)

"FinalizerWatchdogDaemon" daemon prio=5 tid=5 Waiting | group="system" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x32c0c1c0 self=0x7fa451ca00 | sysTid=24121 nice=0 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0x7fb0b76440 | state=S schedstat=( 1770209 11223749 24 ) utm=0 stm=0 core=1 HZ=100 | stack=0x7fb0a74000-0x7fb0a76000 stackSize=1037KB | held mutexes= at java.lang.Object.wait!(Native method) - waiting on <0x0b1f0bfb> (a java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerWatchdogDaemon) at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerWatchdogDaemon.waitForObject(Daemons.java:255) - locked <0x0b1f0bfb> (a java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerWatchdogDaemon) at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerWatchdogDaemon.run(Daemons.java:227) at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)

"Binder_1" prio=5 tid=6 Native | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x32c0c220 self=0x7fab7e3400 | sysTid=24125 nice=0 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0x7fb086e440 | state=S schedstat=( 350663639 1066675783 2687 ) utm=5 stm=30 core=1 HZ=100 | stack=0x7fb0772000-0x7fb0774000 stackSize=1013KB | held mutexes= kernel: __switch_to+0x70/0x7c kernel: binder_thread_read+0xd78/0xeb0 kernel: binder_ioctl_write_read+0x178/0x24c kernel: binder_ioctl+0x2b0/0x5e0 kernel: do_vfs_ioctl+0x4a4/0x578 kernel: SyS_ioctl+0x5c/0x88 kernel: cpu_switch_to+0x48/0x4c native: #00 pc 00000000000697e0 /system/lib64/libc.so (__ioctl+4) native: #01 pc 0000000000072820 /system/lib64/libc.so (ioctl+100) native: #02 pc 000000000002d604 /system/lib64/libbinder.so (_ZN7android14IPCThreadState14talkWithDriverEb+164) native: #03 pc 000000000002de70 /system/lib64/libbinder.so (_ZN7android14IPCThreadState20getAndExecuteCommandEv+24) native: #04 pc 000000000002df8c /system/lib64/libbinder.so (_ZN7android14IPCThreadState14joinThreadPoolEb+76) native: #05 pc 0000000000037cf0 /system/lib64/libbinder.so (???) native: #06 pc 00000000000157cc /system/lib64/libutils.so (_ZN7android6Thread11_threadLoopEPv+208) native: #07 pc 000000000008ef30 /system/lib64/libandroid_runtime.so (_ZN7android14AndroidRuntime15javaThreadShellEPv+96) native: #08 pc 0000000000014ff4 /system/lib64/libutils.so (???) native: #09 pc 0000000000066274 /system/lib64/libc.so (_ZL15__pthread_startPv+52) native: #10 pc 000000000001ef44 /system/lib64/libc.so (__start_thread+16) (no managed stack frames)

"HeapTaskDaemon" daemon prio=5 tid=7 Blocked | group="system" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x32c0c280 self=0x7fa451d400 | sysTid=24122 nice=0 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0x7fb0a71440 | state=S schedstat=( 979409466 32364796 339 ) utm=86 stm=11 core=2 HZ=100 | stack=0x7fb096f000-0x7fb0971000 stackSize=1037KB | held mutexes= kernel: switch_to+0x70/0x7c kernel: futex_wait_queue_me+0xd4/0x12c kernel: futex_wait+0xdc/0x1e4 kernel: do_futex+0xc8/0x8d0 kernel: SyS_futex+0xf8/0x174 kernel: cpu_switch_to+0x48/0x4c native: #00 pc 000000000001c2c8 /system/lib64/libc.so (syscall+28) native: #01 pc 0000000000139614 /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art17ConditionVariable4WaitEPNS_6ThreadE+136) native: #02 pc 0000000000269e6c /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art2gc13TaskProcessor7GetTaskEPNS_6ThreadE+128) native: #03 pc 000000000026a4d4 /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art2gc13TaskProcessor11RunAllTasksEPNS_6ThreadE+120) native: #04 pc 000000000000057c /system/framework/arm64/boot.oat (Java_dalvik_system_VMRuntime_runHeapTasks+128) at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.runHeapTasks(Native method) - waiting to lock an unknown object at java.lang.Daemons$HeapTaskDaemon.run(Daemons.java:355) at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)

"Binder_2" prio=5 tid=8 Native | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x32c0c2e0 self=0x7fab7ef800 | sysTid=24127 nice=0 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0x7fb076f440 | state=S schedstat=( 352887729 992580727 2684 ) utm=9 stm=26 core=0 HZ=100 | stack=0x7fb0673000-0x7fb0675000 stackSize=1013KB | held mutexes= kernel: __switch_to+0x70/0x7c kernel: binder_thread_read+0xd78/0xeb0 kernel: binder_ioctl_write_read+0x178/0x24c kernel: binder_ioctl+0x2b0/0x5e0 kernel: do_vfs_ioctl+0x4a4/0x578 kernel: SyS_ioctl+0x5c/0x88 kernel: cpu_switch_to+0x48/0x4c native: #00 pc 00000000000697e0 /system/lib64/libc.so (__ioctl+4) native: #01 pc 0000000000072820 /system/lib64/libc.so (ioctl+100) native: #02 pc 000000000002d604 /system/lib64/libbinder.so (_ZN7android14IPCThreadState14talkWithDriverEb+164) native: #03 pc 000000000002de70 /system/lib64/libbinder.so (_ZN7android14IPCThreadState20getAndExecuteCommandEv+24) native: #04 pc 000000000002df8c /system/lib64/libbinder.so (_ZN7android14IPCThreadState14joinThreadPoolEb+76) native: #05 pc 0000000000037cf0 /system/lib64/libbinder.so (???) native: #06 pc 00000000000157cc /system/lib64/libutils.so (_ZN7android6Thread11_threadLoopEPv+208) native: #07 pc 000000000008ef30 /system/lib64/libandroid_runtime.so (_ZN7android14AndroidRuntime15javaThreadShellEPv+96) native: #08 pc 0000000000014ff4 /system/lib64/libutils.so (???) native: #09 pc 0000000000066274 /system/lib64/libc.so (_ZL15__pthread_startPv+52) native: #10 pc 000000000001ef44 /system/lib64/libc.so (__start_thread+16) (no managed stack frames)

"RenderThread" prio=5 tid=9 Native | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x32c0c340 self=0x7fa451de00 | sysTid=24132 nice=-4 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0x7fb04bf440 | state=S schedstat=( 27082617153 5929615962 37759 ) utm=2295 stm=413 core=0 HZ=100 | stack=0x7fb03c3000-0x7fb03c5000 stackSize=1013KB | held mutexes= kernel: __switch_to+0x70/0x7c kernel: SyS_epoll_wait+0x2a0/0x324 kernel: SyS_epoll_pwait+0xa4/0x120 kernel: cpu_switch_to+0x48/0x4c native: #00 pc 000000000006898c /system/lib64/libc.so (__epoll_pwait+8) native: #01 pc 000000000001f5a4 /system/lib64/libc.so (epoll_pwait+32) native: #02 pc 000000000001ada4 /system/lib64/libutils.so (_ZN7android6Looper9pollInnerEi+144) native: #03 pc 000000000001b184 /system/lib64/libutils.so (_ZN7android6Looper8pollOnceEiPiS1_PPv+80) native: #04 pc 000000000002b390 /system/lib64/libhwui.so (_ZN7android10uirenderer12renderthread12RenderThread10threadLoopEv+100) native: #05 pc 00000000000157cc /system/lib64/libutils.so (_ZN7android6Thread11_threadLoopEPv+208) native: #06 pc 000000000008ef30 /system/lib64/libandroid_runtime.so (_ZN7android14AndroidRuntime15javaThreadShellEPv+96) native: #07 pc 0000000000014ff4 /system/lib64/libutils.so (???) native: #08 pc 0000000000066274 /system/lib64/libc.so (_ZL15__pthread_startPv+52) native: #09 pc 000000000001ef44 /system/lib64/libc.so (__start_thread+16) (no managed stack frames)

"Binder_3" prio=5 tid=10 Native | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x32c0c3a0 self=0x7fab7fec00 | sysTid=24161 nice=0 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0x7f98287440 | state=S schedstat=( 354202378 1037008558 2681 ) utm=9 stm=26 core=0 HZ=100 | stack=0x7f9818b000-0x7f9818d000 stackSize=1013KB | held mutexes= kernel: __switch_to+0x70/0x7c kernel: binder_thread_read+0xd78/0xeb0 kernel: binder_ioctl_write_read+0x178/0x24c kernel: binder_ioctl+0x2b0/0x5e0 kernel: do_vfs_ioctl+0x4a4/0x578 kernel: SyS_ioctl+0x5c/0x88 kernel: cpu_switch_to+0x48/0x4c native: #00 pc 00000000000697e0 /system/lib64/libc.so (__ioctl+4) native: #01 pc 0000000000072820 /system/lib64/libc.so (ioctl+100) native: #02 pc 000000000002d604 /system/lib64/libbinder.so (_ZN7android14IPCThreadState14talkWithDriverEb+164) native: #03 pc 000000000002de70 /system/lib64/libbinder.so (_ZN7android14IPCThreadState20getAndExecuteCommandEv+24) native: #04 pc 000000000002df8c /system/lib64/libbinder.so (_ZN7android14IPCThreadState14joinThreadPoolEb+76) native: #05 pc 0000000000037cf0 /system/lib64/libbinder.so (???) native: #06 pc 00000000000157cc /system/lib64/libutils.so (_ZN7android6Thread11_threadLoopEPv+208) native: #07 pc 000000000008ef30 /system/lib64/libandroid_runtime.so (_ZN7android14AndroidRuntime15javaThreadShellEPv+96) native: #08 pc 0000000000014ff4 /system/lib64/libutils.so (???) native: #09 pc 0000000000066274 /system/lib64/libc.so (_ZL15__pthread_startPv+52) native: #10 pc 000000000001ef44 /system/lib64/libc.so (__start_thread+16) (no managed stack frames)

"pool-2-thread-1" prio=5 tid=11 Waiting | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x32c0c400 self=0x7f99303e00 | sysTid=24167 nice=0 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0x7f96f71440 | state=S schedstat=( 45292707 8358592 63 ) utm=3 stm=1 core=1 HZ=100 | stack=0x7f96e6f000-0x7f96e71000 stackSize=1037KB | held mutexes= at java.lang.Object.wait!(Native method) - waiting on <0x0100c418> (a java.lang.Object) at java.lang.Thread.parkFor$(Thread.java:1220) - locked <0x0100c418> (a java.lang.Object) at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:299) at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:158) at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2013) at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:410) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1038) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1098) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588) at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)

"hwuiTask1" prio=5 tid=13 Native | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x32c0c460 self=0x7f964f3400 | sysTid=24170 nice=-2 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0x7f95e7a440 | state=S schedstat=( 933990640 701615654 5239 ) utm=72 stm=21 core=0 HZ=100 | stack=0x7f95d7e000-0x7f95d80000 stackSize=1013KB | held mutexes= kernel: __switch_to+0x70/0x7c kernel: futex_wait_queue_me+0xd4/0x12c kernel: futex_wait+0xdc/0x1e4 kernel: do_futex+0xc8/0x8d0 kernel: SyS_futex+0xf8/0x174 kernel: cpu_switch_to+0x48/0x4c native: #00 pc 000000000001c2c8 /system/lib64/libc.so (syscall+28) native: #01 pc 0000000000065f94 /system/lib64/libc.so (_ZL33__pthread_cond_timedwait_relativeP23pthread_cond_internal_tP15pthread_mutex_tPK8timespec+96) native: #02 pc 000000000002c168 /system/lib64/libhwui.so (???) native: #03 pc 00000000000157cc /system/lib64/libutils.so (_ZN7android6Thread11_threadLoopEPv+208) native: #04 pc 000000000008ef30 /system/lib64/libandroid_runtime.so (_ZN7android14AndroidRuntime15javaThreadShellEPv+96) native: #05 pc 0000000000014ff4 /system/lib64/libutils.so (???) native: #06 pc 0000000000066274 /system/lib64/libc.so (_ZL15__pthread_startPv+52) native: #07 pc 000000000001ef44 /system/lib64/libc.so (__start_thread+16) (no managed stack frames)

"AsyncTask #1" prio=5 tid=14 Waiting | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x32c0c4c0 self=0x7f99b78c00 | sysTid=24366 nice=0 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0x7f95f7f440 | state=S schedstat=( 1716248 2236668 11 ) utm=0 stm=0 core=1 HZ=100 | stack=0x7f95e7d000-0x7f95e7f000 stackSize=1037KB | held mutexes= at java.lang.Object.wait!(Native method) - waiting on <0x0ba2fe71> (a java.lang.Object) at java.lang.Thread.parkFor$(Thread.java:1220) - locked <0x0ba2fe71> (a java.lang.Object) at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:299) at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:158) at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2013) at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:410) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1038) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1098) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588) at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)

"AsyncTask #2" prio=5 tid=15 Waiting | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x32c0c520 self=0x7fb0633a00 | sysTid=24367 nice=0 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0x7f93242440 | state=S schedstat=( 1826717 722656 10 ) utm=0 stm=0 core=0 HZ=100 | stack=0x7f93140000-0x7f93142000 stackSize=1037KB | held mutexes= at java.lang.Object.wait!(Native method) - waiting on <0x0a52f456> (a java.lang.Object) at java.lang.Thread.parkFor$(Thread.java:1220) - locked <0x0a52f456> (a java.lang.Object) at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:299) at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:158) at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2013) at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:410) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1038) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1098) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588) at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)

"hwuiTask2" prio=5 tid=16 Native | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x32c0c580 self=0x7f9a4fb400 | sysTid=24368 nice=-2 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0x7f9313d440 | state=S schedstat=( 26998332 50694997 175 ) utm=0 stm=2 core=2 HZ=100 | stack=0x7f93041000-0x7f93043000 stackSize=1013KB | held mutexes= kernel: __switch_to+0x70/0x7c kernel: futex_wait_queue_me+0xd4/0x12c kernel: futex_wait+0xdc/0x1e4 kernel: do_futex+0xc8/0x8d0 kernel: SyS_futex+0xf8/0x174 kernel: cpu_switch_to+0x48/0x4c native: #00 pc 000000000001c2c8 /system/lib64/libc.so (syscall+28) native: #01 pc 0000000000065f94 /system/lib64/libc.so (_ZL33__pthread_cond_timedwait_relativeP23pthread_cond_internal_tP15pthread_mutex_tPK8timespec+96) native: #02 pc 000000000002c168 /system/lib64/libhwui.so (???) native: #03 pc 00000000000157cc /system/lib64/libutils.so (_ZN7android6Thread11_threadLoopEPv+208) native: #04 pc 000000000008ef30 /system/lib64/libandroid_runtime.so (_ZN7android14AndroidRuntime15javaThreadShellEPv+96) native: #05 pc 0000000000014ff4 /system/lib64/libutils.so (???) native: #06 pc 0000000000066274 /system/lib64/libc.so (_ZL15__pthread_startPv+52) native: #07 pc 000000000001ef44 /system/lib64/libc.so (__start_thread+16) (no managed stack frames)

"hwuiTask3" prio=5 tid=17 Native | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x32c0c5e0 self=0x7fb062ce00 | sysTid=24369 nice=-2 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0x7f9303e440 | state=S schedstat=( 6209634 12563853 53 ) utm=0 stm=0 core=1 HZ=100 | stack=0x7f92f42000-0x7f92f44000 stackSize=1013KB | held mutexes= kernel: __switch_to+0x70/0x7c kernel: futex_wait_queue_me+0xd4/0x12c kernel: futex_wait+0xdc/0x1e4 kernel: do_futex+0xc8/0x8d0 kernel: SyS_futex+0xf8/0x174 kernel: cpu_switch_to+0x48/0x4c native: #00 pc 000000000001c2c8 /system/lib64/libc.so (syscall+28) native: #01 pc 0000000000065f94 /system/lib64/libc.so (_ZL33__pthread_cond_timedwait_relativeP23pthread_cond_internal_tP15pthread_mutex_tPK8timespec+96) native: #02 pc 000000000002c168 /system/lib64/libhwui.so (???) native: #03 pc 00000000000157cc /system/lib64/libutils.so (_ZN7android6Thread11_threadLoopEPv+208) native: #04 pc 000000000008ef30 /system/lib64/libandroid_runtime.so (_ZN7android14AndroidRuntime15javaThreadShellEPv+96) native: #05 pc 0000000000014ff4 /system/lib64/libutils.so (???) native: #06 pc 0000000000066274 /system/lib64/libc.so (_ZL15__pthread_startPv+52) native: #07 pc 000000000001ef44 /system/lib64/libc.so (__start_thread+16) (no managed stack frames)

"OkHttp ConnectionPool" daemon prio=5 tid=19 TimedWaiting | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x32c0c640 self=0x7f99db8400 | sysTid=24491 nice=0 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0x7f95d7b440 | state=S schedstat=( 7143596 339374 17 ) utm=0 stm=0 core=3 HZ=100 | stack=0x7f95c79000-0x7f95c7b000 stackSize=1037KB | held mutexes= at java.lang.Object.wait!(Native method) - waiting on <0x0ec6e9eb> (a java.lang.Object) at java.lang.Thread.parkFor$(Thread.java:1220) - locked <0x0ec6e9eb> (a java.lang.Object) at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:299) at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:198) at java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferStack.awaitFulfill(SynchronousQueue.java:430) at java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferStack.transfer(SynchronousQueue.java:332) at java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue.poll(SynchronousQueue.java:911) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1037) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1098) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588) at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

I hope someone can help me, Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Vimeo video stops playing on Android 6 devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41430007/vimeo-video-stops-playing-on-android-6-devices)